# QSqlQuery will fail when there is "select @variable = xxx" in a multi-statement query

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

[QSqlQuery](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#nextResult) perfectly supports multi-statement query. And I'm working on SQL Server 2019.

```
QSqlDatabase db;
//some database connecting code.

QString sQuery = R"(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Foo;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Bar;)";

QSqlQuery q = db.exec(sQuery);

//Read dataset 1
while(q.next()){
//process the data
}

//Read dataset 2
q.nextResult();
while(q.next()){
//process the data
}
```

It works pretty well.

But if I add a variable, it goes south.

```
QString sQuery = R"(DECLARE @SomeId INT;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Foo;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Bar;
SELECT TOP 1 @SomeId = 4;)";

qDebug() << q.isSelect();//true
qDebug() << q.isValid();//false
```

The first result is still a select but not valid, the second is in that case as well -- `q.next()` would always be false.

PS: Actually I'm using `SELECT TOP 1 @SomeId = 4;` in the first query. But I'm worried someone would argue `SELECT TOP 1 @SomeId = 4;` is not a query, you should use `q.nextResult();` to skip it. But even I put it in the last, it still doesn't work.

Did I find a Qt bug?

Comment: Why are you just putting arbitrary `TOP 1`s here? This will result in arbitrary results, and it doesn't make sense for the variable assignment query; you're assigning a scalar value and there's no `FROM` to mean there would be multiple rows.

Comment: @ThomA, because the real query is something like `SELECT TOP 1 @SomeId = Id FROM Tab WHERE Tab.someFlag = 0`, I just simplified it. And it's not the decisive factor.

Answer (score -1):

Try enclosing the variable like this...

`@SomeId = '4'`

you may also need to preface the variable with WHERE statement

```
SELECT TOP 1 SomeId WHERE @SomeId = '4';
```

Lastly, you may need to specify the table like your other queries.

```
SELECT TOP 1 SomeId FROM foobar WHERE @SomeId = '4';
```